# GUI Extension for SiteEdit UI

Tags: 2011, siteedit, siteedit-2009

We have upgraded to 2011 SP1 from 5.3, also upgraded to SiteEdit 2009 SP3.

Our content Editor team want all the component list on new SiteEdit UI, which used to be there in old SitEdit.

Please check screen shot

[image]

As per Tridion support this particular feature is not supported. Can this feature be provided using Tridion GUI extensions? Or do I have to create some browser extension to regex the source for component-id to support it.

Comment: Are you using SiteEdit 2009 SP3 or the User Interface update for SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 (aka UI 2012, the new SiteEdit)? I think both are possible for 2011 SP1, but they have a complete different extension model.

Comment: I am using SiteEdit2009 SP3. Do SDL LiveContent have some material on it?

Comment: SiteEdit 2009 SP3 is definitely listed in the documentation portal, if extensions on it are mentioned in there too I don't know (they are possible but I can't remember the exact supported level of them). In any case, I can only recommend that you ditch the old SiteEdit and use the User Interface update for SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 (the new SiteEdit) instead. That has an open extension model and will prepare you more for the future rather then staying stuck in the past (same would count for an upgrade to 2013 by the way, which comes with Experience Manager, which is the new SiteEdit).

Comment: Right now we are not in the stage to update to 2012 UI update. for now i want know how to extend current SE2009 sp3 UI to achieve mentioned feature.

Comment: best I can give you then is follow the documentation http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SiteEdit_2009_SP3/concept_E3F75CD7E57041F2B63A56602E63C353 ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion))

Comment: What does the feature that you're missing do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Please check the screenshot. in old siteedit we get list of components on the page.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't show what is behind the menu option. What happens when you click on a Component in the "Edit Component" submenu?

Comment: its shows all the available component on page, screen shot is actually cropped one, so its showing only component icons.

Comment: We updated to UI-2012 & created UI extension to achieve this functionality. let me know if anyone need this in their project.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you template out a list of component IDs being used on the Page. Then you can insert your extension logic to retrieve this value and build the dialog as required?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Tridion.Web.UI;
using Tridion.Web.UI.SiteEdit.Extensions;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace SEExtension
{        public void OnPageLoaded(TridionWebPage page)
        {
        //You use the ExtensionHelper class in the UI Extensions framework to interact with the GUI control framework

        ExtensionHelper.CurrentPage = page;

        // Access to the 'page' object is possible here
        // Get array/collection of Components from Page (output by the template for example)
        // Consider that you may have retrieved Dynamic Component Presentations on this page too - do you want these to be injected into this list of Components? etc.
        /*
        { seExtensionInfo: { 
            pub: 22, 
            components { 
                component: {
                    id: 123, 
                    title: 'comp a'
                },
                component: {
                    id: 456, 
                    title: 'comp b'
                }
            }
        }
        */
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We updated to UI-2012 & created UI extension to achieve this functionality. let me know if anyone need this in their project.

Comment: Hi Raj, perhaps you could share the extension with the Community? that would be great for others that come across this question also.